# DbContext encontra Connection String em Projeto Web, mas não em projeto Console App

Tags: entity-framework, connectionstring

Tenho um projeto `Class Library` que contém o contexto, arquivos de configuração e classes de acesso ao banco de dados. A referência dele em um projeto Asp.Net MVC funciona normalmente, ele acessa os dados e etc, mas em um projeto do tipo `Console Application`o contexto não "carrega" a `Connection String`que está em `App.config`, sendo que é a mesma de `Web.config`.

Classe de contexto:

```
 public class SiteContext : DbContext
 {
     public SiteContext () : base("SiteBanco")
     {
         Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
         Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
     }
  }
```

`Web.config` e `App.config`

> `<connectionStrings>
>    <add name="SiteBanco" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER-TEST\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=BaseTeste;Integrated Security=False;User ID=***;Password=*****;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
>   </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Este App.config se encontra na Console Application?

Comment: Sim, está no mesmo local...

Comment: @JcSaint faz o seguinte teste, force ele a procurar o nome dessa forma:
`public SiteContext () : base("name=SiteBanco")` e posta o que aconteceu  aqui nos comentários.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic funcionou, valeu...

Comment: @JcSaint eu deixei então também como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force que ele procure pelo determinado nome da sua `ConnectionStrings` dessa forma: `name=SiteBanco`, isso servirá tanto para `app.config` e `web.config`:

***Código final:***

```
public class SiteContext : DbContext
{
     public SiteContext () : base("name=SiteBanco")
     {
         Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
         Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
     }
}
```

***Referencias:***

- [Entity Framework Connections and Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592674(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [Database/Model First with connection string in app.config/web.config file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592674(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_3)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta esse:

```
    public SiteContext ()
        : base("SiteBanco", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
     Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
     Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }
```